# How to set the data format for the row in Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to set the data type for row in Excel to date format ('yyyy-MM-dd') and for that I have written following piece of code:

```
....
Row r = null;
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    //CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(
            workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    for(int i =0;i < 2;i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                r = sheet.getRow(0);
                r.setRowStyle(cellStyle);
                break;
            case 1:
                r = sheet.getRow(1);
                r.setRowStyle(cellStyle);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
....
```

I have posted formatting for only first two rows for reference. But when I run my code and open the Excel sheet and check the format of cells in first two rows then its general only. Change is not getting reflected in Excel sheet. I am not getting what I did wrong here.

Comment: Do you have existing cells in those rows? If so, what happens when you also set the new style on those cells as well?

Comment: I am creating excel sheet newly. SO It won't be having any data in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating this excel sheet from scratch than it doesn't have rows yet. I get a `NullPointerException` on `getRow(0)` in a fresh sheet. Try using `createRow(0)` instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {
        File excelFile = new File("C:/temp/test.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheetname");

        Row r = null;
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        // CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                r = sheet.createRow(0);
                r.setRowStyle(cellStyle);
                break;
            case 1:
                r = sheet.createRow(1);
                r.setRowStyle(cellStyle);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelFile)) {
            workbook.write(out);
        }
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(excelFile);
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use a switch case. A better solution would be to use  the current iteration index instead to create the new row.

Comment: I am using switch because for different different group of rows I will be having different style.

Comment: @Moh-AW: when I run your code it works fine. But when I use the same in my code it's not giving required format. I am getting workbook from utility class in which I am creating excel file. Don't know what is getting wrong there

Comment: @Madhusudan Can you add the workbook creation code to your question?

Comment: hey...sorry. It's working now. I did a small mistake. Thanks :)